# Coq : mutually recursive definitions with [mrec] in InteractionTrees Library

Tags: coq, mutual-recursion

I'm studying [this great library for Representing Recursive and Impure Programs in Coq](https://github.com/DeepSpec/InteractionTrees)

I am having problems with mutual recursion (very first example in [documentation](https://deepspec.github.io/InteractionTrees/5.0.0/ITree.Interp.Recursion.html#mrec) gives me an error)
https://deepspec.github.io/InteractionTrees/5.0.0/ITree.Interp.Recursion.html#mrec

```
Inductive D : Type -> Type :=
| Even : nat -> D bool
| Odd : nat -> D bool.

Definition def : D ~> itree (D +' void1) := fun _ d =>
  match d with
  | Even n => match n with
              | O => ret true
              | S m => ITree.trigger (Odd m)
              end
  | Odd n => match n with
             | O => ret false
             | S m => ITree.trigger (Even m)
             end
end.
```

This is the Error I am getting

```
Error:
In environment
T : Type
d : D T
n : nat
m : nat
The term "ITree.trigger (Odd m)" has type "itree (D +' void1) ?T0"
while it is expected to have type
 "itree (D +' void1) ?T@{T0:=T; T1:=bool}" (cannot satisfy constraint
"D bool" == "(D +' void1) ?T0").
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

By the way, I managed to use generic [rec] interface of the library's [Interp] module to define a single recursive function (no errors, no problems, and working example is given in tutorial ([Introduction.v file](https://github.com/DeepSpec/InteractionTrees/blob/master/tutorial/Introduction.v))). But I couldn't find working example for more general [mrec] which allows multiple, mutually recursive definitions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ITree.trigger` (not overloaded) with `trigger` (overloaded).

Compilable example:

```
From ExtLib Require Import Monad.
From ITree Require Import ITree.

Inductive D : Type -> Type :=
| Even : nat -> D bool
| Odd : nat -> D bool.

Definition def : D ~> itree (D +' void1) := fun _ d =>
  match d with
  | Even n => match n with
              | O => ret true
              | S m => trigger (Odd m)
              end
  | Odd n => match n with
             | O => ret false
             | S m => trigger (Even m)
             end
end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! But It was I who added ITree.trigger... otherwise I am getting ```Error: The reference trigger was not found in the current environment. ```


Maybe I forgot to import something?

Comment: How did you import the itree library? The recommended way is `From ITree Require Import ITree.`